# Retrieving and inserting multiple entries in MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I'm trying to create a form that retrieves data from a database and then allows me to add data to one column for multiple entries.

Every entry has an ID, a lot of other fields, and a category. I am trying to add these categories for every ID in the database using one form.

I came up with the solution below, but (of course)this only inserts the LAST entry in the form, because the variable ID is changed with every new row.
The form I have now shows me what I want to see, but it does not save it the way I need it to.

The question is, (how) can I make a form that has all entries in the database with a dropdown menu next to it,
lets me select the right category from the dropdown, and save it to the database?

The form:

```
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM aw");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$row[ID].'."> '.$row[ID].'</td><td>';
echo '

<select name="cat" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option value="C1">category1</option>
<option value="C2"">category2</option>
</select></td></tr>
';
}


?>
<tr><td><input type="submit" title="SAVE" ></td></tr>
</form>
```

The insert.php

```
$sql="REPLACE INTO aw (ID,cat)
VALUES
('$_POST[ID]','$_POST[cat]')";




if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I changed my code according to Tom's answer and I now have the following:
This does print the values like they should be, but it still saves only the last entry into the database. I'm sure I must be missing something here..

```
$name = $_POST['ID'];
$category = $_POST['cat'];

foreach( $name as $key => $n ) {
$sql="REPLACE INTO aw (ID,cat)
VALUES
('$n','$category[$key]')";


  print "The id is ".$n.", category is ".$category[$key]."<br>";

}
```

Comment: Please use PDO instead of mysqli_* functions. Or at least use prepared statements. Also please be aware that directly inserting posted values into queries are a critical security issue, please read up on sql injections.

Comment: PDO does not prevent sql injection by default, its a better and safer method but does not "simply remove threats"

Comment: Edited answer, is this what you mean?

Comment: The mysqli functions are not deprecated.  The mysql ones are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>First of all, use [PDO::Mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), the SQL functions you are using are a bit deprecated and do not focus much on security. At the moment your code is vulnerable to SQL injections and your output is sensitive to XSS attacks (always sanitize output).</s>

I was wrong, MySQL is deprecated but MySQL**i** is not! I do prefer using [PDO::Mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) because of the range of databases it supports (MySQL**i** only supports a MySQL database, PDO::Mysql supports many more)

Now to your original question, you can create a sort of array. By making `name="ID"` to `name="ID[]"` and `name="cat"` to `name="cat[]"`.

Now you can do

```
$name = $_POST['ID'];
$category = $_POST['cat'];

foreach( $name as $key => $n ) {
  print "The id is ".$n.", category is ".$category[$key];
}
```

Comment: The mysqli functions are not deprecated.  The mysql ones are.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, but I guess I'm still making a mistake somewhere, I did what you said and changed it to ID[] and cat[]
It does print it in the right way, but when I try to insert it into the database it still only saves the last entry.
I also changed my input.php to the following:

$name = $_POST['ID'];
$category = $_POST['cat'];

foreach( $name as $key => $n ) {
$sql="REPLACE INTO aw (ID,cat)
VALUES
('$n','$category[$key]')";


  print "The id is ".$n.", category is ".$category[$key]."<br>";

}

sorry, this is not very readable, i'll edit it in the question! (first time user)

Comment: You create your sql query in the for loop but execute it outside the for-loop. Insert the if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  } inside the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your using the name elements regardless of how many rows..
So name="ID" & name="cat" needs to change on each row or have an array type

you could use something like name="ID[]" as this would append/ create an array to $_POST['ID']... but you still would want to change your SQL query to handle each of these.

**EDIT**

If i understand, you want to be able to identify a row from the table so you can use that in the database?? One way todo this is when creating the table.. Give the TR a id/name attribute that is the row id from the database.

Then can simply know by checking that if your using the select menu from row #4, you check the id/name attribute of the current row and you have your database id.

```
<tr id='my_row_1'>
  <td class='colName'>John</td>
  <td class='colPhone'>1111</td>
  <td class='colOther'>....</td>
</tr>
<tr id='my_row_2'>
  <td class='colName'>Bill</td>
  <td class='colPhone'>2222</td>
  <td class='colOther'>....</td>
</tr>
<tr id='my_row_3'>
  <td class='colName'>Roger</td>
  <td class='colPhone'>3333</td>
  <td class='colOther'>....</td>
</tr>
```

With something like the above, Say i had a button in on of the columns... When i click on that button.. all i have todo is find the parent TR and get its id value.... Then explode it by "_" and get the last piece to have the id..

So your PHP would generate the id easily... Also, using a form would not be the best case here.. Using multiple forms within a table is... wasteful... sort of ..

I would suggest more so, having a button that simple calls a js function which will then post/ajax/jquery what you need from that row.

--- Trying to understand exactly what you need??

Comment: Yes, I get that, but wouldn't that give me a problem when inserting them to the database? The have to be added in the 'cat' and 'ID' columns..